# Django-autocomplete-light textwidget display all the values before typing

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I use django-autocomoplete-light to make an autocopmlete-field for tags.
I decided to use TextWidget for my form because with ChoiceWidget I can't get the value from web-page. The problem is that when input field is activating, the values displays immediately in the drop-down. The ChoiceWidget works a little bit different. It starts display the values only when some characters are inputed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide some code I don't know exactly how your autocomplete registry code looks like, but specifying the **minimum amount of characters** to **0** does the trick.

Slightly modified example from the [docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html):

```
import autocomplete_light.shortcuts as al

al.register(your_model,
    attrs={
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 0,
    },
)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. As a usual my inattention bring me problems :-)